# Copying large video files to external hard drive (connected via a SATA III to USB 3.0 hub) universally causes file corruption

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, sata, ext4

The files are perfectly fine on my server's local SSD, but when I try to copy them to the ext4 logical volume I have set up on top of a volume group that contains only this HDD, where the size of the LV is the size of the HDD, the video files get completely corrupted. I tried copying over a simple text file, and that transferred fine, however. I've tried using both cp and rsync to do the copy, and in both cases the video files get corrupted.

In case it's relevant, I had to set ext4 to `data=journal` and turn off delayed block allocation, because that was causing a ton of errors during a previous transfer attempt.

In case it's further relevant, here's the SATA III to USB 3.0 hub I'm using: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B3MGYK1N?psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B3MGYK1N)

Comment: At first sight this looks like a bad disk.

Comment: I was worried about that. It's a brand new Western Digital Red 4TB HDD though that I just bought. Is there any way I could check whether the disk is good or not?

Comment: Yes, try another disk.

Comment: backup, then check SMART data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology. I've had drives damaged in shipping before.  RMA was fun. /s They assumed I would buy drives, kick em around a bit and then return them...

Comment: @Gantendo alright I ran the smartctl conveyance tests and it passed, now I'm running the extended self-test, we'll see if that turns up anything. It's gonna take awhile tho (330 mins lol)

Comment: Interpreting SMART parameters correctly is one of the dark arts so don't expect a simple binary keep or toss.

Comment: 1. Try *pushing* the files, i.e., from the server, copy to the PC with the ext4 partition. 2. Check that the files are being treated as *binary*, not *ASCII*. Though I *don't* see how that might be an issue in cp or rsync, in FTP it *is* a concern.

Comment: @Gantendo well, turns out the SMART attributes weren't that hard to read in this case, I think, because the very first one was: `Raw_Read_Error_Rate`, with a value of 200, when the vendor worst possible value is.... 200, and the vendor threshold for it having failed is 051... lmao. I'm gonna go return it.

Comment: @AlexisPurslane F. Makes you wonder wtf happened to it because it would not be allowed to leave the factory like this.

Comment: @AlexisPurslane If it is "value" (not "raw value") then most likely the bigger the better and 200 is the best (no error at all).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski if you look at the answer I just posted to myself, I copied over the SMART attributes, and the "worst" column lists 200 as worst, and the threshold column has 51, so it looks like larger means worse?

Comment: @Gantendo i got it off newegg, they shipped it to me raw, no product box, just an anti-static bag and some bubble wrap, so... it probably got drop kicked to my doorstep and died.

Comment: "Worst" is probably historical data. E.g. the worst temperature was 108. It's true that "Interpreting SMART parameters correctly is one of the dark arts"; for some fields it's "the bigger the better", for others the opposite; sometimes up to 100, sometimes up to 200; often vendor-specific. The raw values of 0 for many fields *most likely* indicate these are OK. E.g. my WD disk has the following `Raw_Read_Error_Rate`: value 100, worst 100, threshold 016, raw 0; Seagate: value 082, worst 064, threshold 006, raw 144918848. If I should worry, I should worry for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: the problem is not the hard drive at all, it was the cheap SATA III to USB 3.0 hub I was using, corrupting the data. I got a better one, and now it works fine!**

It turns out I was actually misreading the SMART attributes, as the commenters said.

---

Turns out the drive was just fubar. I ran

```bash
sudo smartctl -t long /dev/<device>
```

waited till mid day the next day, then ran

```bash
sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/<device>
```

to check that the check was done. It was, so I ran

```bash
sudo smartctl -a /dev/<device>
```

and got the smart attributes:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       115
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   112   108   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

This confirmed my fears that the hard drive was faulty: see how the raw read error rate value is 200, which is literally the worst possible value according to the vendor, and far above the acceptable threshold of 51? Same for the seek error rate? Yeah. Drive's fubar.

Comment: I guess it's not the full output of `smartctl -a`. There should be `SMART Self-test log` somewhere below. What does it say? Because of many raw values being `0` I expect it says there was no error. I think your interpretation is wrong and according to SMART the disk is fine.

Comment: I'll post the full SMART output in a bit. You may be right, but then I'm not sure what could be causing the corruption beside the disk being bad? I already set the return in motion so I'm gonna return it anyway and hope for the best...